# Does ffmpeg work on a shared hosting environment running under Windows 2008/IIS 7?

Tags: shared-hosting, ffmpeg

I emailed a company a question and the response was to "check with the vendors of these products if it can run on a shared hosting environment running under Windows 2008/IIS 7"

I never used Windows 2008/IIS 7 nor have a clue what the difference between shared hosting and other types of hosting. Will ffmpeg run?

Comment: I used to make ffmpeg run on shared hosting environmens, but on Linux. If there is ffmpeg for Windows (or you can compile one from svn), then there should be no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect it to. Typically in a shared hosting environment you only have access to a limited number of ports. Typically only port 80 is a available. For example if multiple users attempt to run a service that binds to a specific port, then only one can grab the port, everyone else is out of luck.

So you want some variation of a VPS (virtual private server) where your running under a virtual machine, but it looks like its your own private machine. You get a complete set of ports to bind services to.

I've been using slicehost for a few years and been happy with them, you could look at amazon web services, there are many choices.